# Extract and rearrange from file

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, command-line

I have file which I want to extract and rearrange certain data , Old file contains a raw data this file is Input

```
reference:cve,2017-8962
sid:45885
reference:cve,2016-10033
reference:cve,2016-10034
reference:cve,2016-10045
reference:cve,2016-10074
sid:45917
reference:cve,2017-8046
sid:45976
reference:cve,2018-6577
reference:cve,2018-6578
sid:46062
```

and the below file is the New file contains the required output

```
reference:cve,2017-8962
sid:45885
reference:cve,2016-10033
sid:45917
reference:cve,2016-10034
sid:45917
reference:cve,2016-10045
sid:45917
reference:cve,2016-10074
sid:45917
reference:cve,2017-8046
sid:45976
reference:cve,2018-6577
sid:46062
reference:cve,2018-6578
sid:46062
```

.

Explanation:for eample sid:45917 there are four references they are (reference:cve,2016-10033
reference:cve,2016-10034
reference:cve,2016-10045
reference:cve,2016-10074), we need to split each reference and append sid one below the other (**note: sid is always followed by reference**), like this there are repetitive blocks, so if there are multiple references we need to append them in New file order.

Comment: I have no idea what your goal is. Please try explaining more precisly what your input and expected output is.

Comment: Please copy your complete input data as a code block, not as a picture.

Comment: Kindly post the input data and required output

Comment: Guys edited, Please have a look.

Comment: example and explanation are conflicting. In the source, is sid: *before* or *after* *reference:* ?

Comment: sid is after reference.

Comment: so to understand :

 - in original, there are multiple *reference:* followed by a single *sid:* that corresponds to them
 - in the output, there are multiple *reference:* each one followed by its corresponding sid ?

Comment: To define more precisely,  if there are more references @single hand then divide that append sid in between.

Comment: I dont' understand you explanations. Just try my code bellow and say if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to use *post-ponned* `sid:`s (multipe `references:` followed by their single `sids:` => pairs of `references:` and `sid:`), two solution.

---

### Solution 1 : reversing

Simple use the `tac` command (it's *cat* in the reverse order) to reverse the input and the output : `tac input | awk | tac > output`

For awk part, just duplicate the `sid:`s:

```
gawk '/^sid:/{sid=$0};/^reference:/{print sid "\n" $0}'
```

---

### Solution 2 : array

Store the `reference:`s in an array as they come and then spit them back out when encountering corresponding `sid:`

```
gawk 'BEGIN{r=0};/^reference:/{ref[r++]=$0};/^sid:/{for(n=0;n<r;n++){print ref[n] "\n" $0};r=0}' /tmp/test.txt
```

`/^reference:/{ref[r++]=$0}` : for each line which begins by ref... store the line in an array and move the 'r' pointer to the next element.

`/^sid:/{for(n=0;n<r;n++){print ref[n] "\n" $0};r=0}` : whenever a line begins with sid, walk the whole array until the r pointer (for...) and for each element, print the stored ref and the current line (=sid), then reset the r back to beginning so we begin again with the next references.

Comment: Solution 2 : I have tried it works , please @DrYark  kindly explain me the solution 2. just osm*

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { i=0; }
/^reference:/ { ref[i++] = $0; }
/^sid:/ { for(j=0; j<i; j++) { print ref[j]; print; } i=0; }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN { i=0; }` Initialize variable to make sure it is interpreted as a numeric value `0`, not as an empty string `""`.
- `/^reference:/ { ref[i++] = $0; }` For every line that starts with `reference:` (`^` is an anchor to the beginning of the line) copy the whole line `$0` to an array element `ref[i]` and increment the index `i++`
- `/^sid:/ { ... }` for every line that startts with `sid:` ...
- `for(j=0; j<i; j++) { ... }` As `i` points to the array element after the last used one, loop over all array elements that have been written to using index `j`,
- `print ref[j];` print the contents of the array element, i.e. a saved `reference:` line
- `print;` print the current line, i.e. the `sid:` line
- `i=0;` reset the array index to the beginning for the next group of `reference:` lines

The script is based on the following assumptions:

- The input consists of a series of block where every block contains

  - a sequence of one or more `reference:` lines followed by
  - a single `sid:` line
- The last line must be a `sid:` line.
- Non-matching lines will be ignored.

With the original question I assumed the wrong direction of the conversion. The second script converts in the opposite direction:

```
awk 'BEGIN { oldsid=""; ref=""; }
/^reference:/ { ref=$0; }
/^sid:/ { if(oldsid != $0) { if(oldsid != "") print oldsid; } if(ref!="")print ref; oldsid=$0; }
END { if (oldsid != "") print oldsid; }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN { oldsid=""; ref=""; }` Initialize variables for clarity, not really necessary.
- `/^reference:/ { ref=$0; }` For every line that startts with `reference:` save the line `$0` to variable `ref`, don't print it yet.
- `/^sid:/ { ... }` For every line that starts with `sid:` ...
- `if(oldsid != $0) { if(oldsid != "") print oldsid; }` If the `sid:` line has changed now, the last `reference:` line saved in `ref` belongs to the new `sid:`, so we don't print it yet. If `oldsid` is not empty we can print it now as the previous block of `reference:` lines with the same `sid:` is finished. `oldsid` will be empty when we find the first `sid:`.
- `if(ref!="")print ref;` If we have a saved `reference:`, print it now. (Either we have just closed the previous block with the corresponding `sid:` line or we know now that the current `reference:` has the same `sid:` as the previous one.) The check for empty string is not really necessary as I assume every `sid:` line is preceded by a `reference:` line.
- `oldsid=$0;` save the current `sid:` line for the comparison when we get the next one. The current line is not printed yet.
- `END { if (oldsid != "") print oldsid; }` At the end print the last saved `sid:` line if there is any. (If the input file is empty it will not print an empty line here.)

This script is based on these assumptions:

- every `reference:` is followed by a `sid:`
- all pairs of `reference:` and `sid:` with the same `sid:` line follow each other

Comment: Sorry edited, Please check

Comment: Thanks @Bodo request you to kindly explain me the awk second snippet.Magic

Comment: @chandu: I added explanation for both `awk` scripts

Comment: Thanks @Bodo for your time and so nicely explained..